# What is SynchronizationContext.IsWaitNotificationRequired for?

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library

[`SynchronizationContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.aspx) has a property called [`IsWaitNotificationRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.iswaitnotificationrequired.aspx). Of its purpose, the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.iswaitnotificationrequired.aspx) have this to say:

> Determines if wait notification is required.
>
> true if wait notification is required; otherwise, false.

Gosh, that clarifies things.

What exactly is this "wait notification", and when / why would it be required / not required? Is `IsWaitNotificationRequired` something along the lines of [`Control.InvokeRequired`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx), or is this something different?

Comment: This answer may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5109784/245183

Comment: @OndrejTucny, I'm not sure what to make of that answer... does that mean that it lets you specify which WinAPI calls `Monitor.Enter` and `Monitor.Exit` actually use to wait on a lock? What happens when `IsWaitNotificationRequired` is false?

Comment: The internal WaitHelper() method is the key, it invokes the handle waiting code inside the CLR that's safe for COM single threaded apartments.  It pumps a message loop it the thread is STA to ensure that the wait doesn't cause deadlock.  WPF needs it.  Review MsgWaitForMultipleObjects().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for infrastructure that allows hooking up into CLR synchronisation wait routine. This blog post explains how this works: https://web.archive.org/web/20080503180352/http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2008/02/27/HookingCLRBlockingCallsWithSynchronizationContext.aspx

This property will always return `false` if this behaviour has not been specifically overridden in a subclass of  `SynchronizationContext` and if it does your overridden implementation of the `Wait` method gets called.